# v-calendar does not highlight dates inside props when selected

Tags: javascript, css, vcalendar

I'm trying to highlight my vue calendar based on start and end dates that I select. I am following the documentation but it doesn't seem to provide much detail on how to select dates https://vcalendar.io/attributes.html

currently I am able to select dates and store them into my state using the dayClicked method but when I use the dates prop inside attributes to set the highlighted days nothing happens. I have noticed that if I just

replace

`dates: { start: new Date(year, month, this.selectedDay.day), end: new Date(year, month, this.endDate.day)},`

with

```
  dates: { start: new Date(year, month, 12), end: new Date(year, month, 14)},
```

it works fine, but I have checked to make sure the values being passed are integers so I'm assuming it just doesn't have access to data() for some reason... I'm hoping someone can help me find a way around this problem and pass my days to the calendar component somehow

Any help is appreciated :)

```
<template>
 <div id="calendarContainer">
    
 <DatePicker is-range :attributes='attributes'
 @dayclick='dayClicked'
 />
    
    <button class="arrowBtnsLeft" @click="monthBack">&#60;</button>
    <button class="arrowBtnsRight" @click="monthForward">&#62;</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import DatePicker from 'v-calendar/lib/components/calendar.umd'

export default {
  name: 'calendar', 
  components:{
      DatePicker,
},
  data() {
  
      const date = new Date()
      const year = date.getFullYear()
      const month = date.getMonth()

  return {
       selectedDay: {day: 14},
       endDate: {day: 17},
    
        attributes: [
      // This is a single attribute
      {
     
        key: 'today',
        highlight:{
            start: {fillMode: 'outline'},
            end: {fillMode: 'outline'},
            color:'red',
            fillMod:'light'
        },
        dates: { start: new Date(year, month, this.selectedDay.day), end: new Date(year, month, this.endDate.day)},
       
        
      
      }
    ]
    
  }
  
},
onMounted(){
      console.log(this.range)
  },
methods: {
    dayClicked(day) {
    if(this.selectedDay == null){
      this.selectedDay = day;
      //change days styles to be blue
     

    }else if(this.selectedDay!== null && this.endDate == null){
        this.endDate = day;
        //change days styles to be blue
        //change days days inbetween to be outlined
        console.log('start',this.selectedDay, 'end', this.endDate)
        this.selectedDay.classes.push('start')
        this.endDate.classes.push('end')
     }else{
        //remove classes for start and end
         this.selectedDay.classes.pop()
         this.endDate.classes.pop()

        this.selectedDay = day;
         this.endDate = null;
        
     }
     

    },
        
       monthForward(){
        let newtime = this.context.selectedYMD.split('-')
        var timestring = ''
          newtime[1] = parseInt(newtime[1])+1
          newtime[1] = newtime[1].toString()

        for( let i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
          console.log(newtime[i])
          if(i < 2){
          timestring+=newtime[i]+'-'
          }else{
            timestring+=newtime[i]
          }
        }

        this.value = timestring
      
      
       },
       monthBack(){
         let newtime = this.context.selectedYMD.split('-')
        var timestring = ''
          newtime[1] = parseInt(newtime[1])-1
          newtime[1] = newtime[1].toString()


        for( let i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
          console.log(newtime[i])
          if(i < 2){
          timestring+=newtime[i]+'-'
          }else{
            timestring+=newtime[i]
          }
        }

        this.value = timestring
       }
    }
    
    
}
</script>

<style>
#calendarContainer{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
.inTrip{
  border-top:1px solid gray;
  border-bottom:1px solid gray;
}

.start{
border-radius: 20px;
border-left:1px solid gray;
border-right:none;
background-color:#2E9CFF;
color:white;

}
.end{
border-radius: 20px;
border-right:1px solid gray;
border-left:none;
background-color:#2E9CFF;
color:white;

}

.arrowBtnsLeft{
  position:absolute;
  top:.8em;
  left:12em;
  background-color:#afd7f78e;
  color:#2E9CFF;
  border: none;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.arrowBtnsRight{
  position:absolute;
  top:.8em;
  left:14em;
  background-color:#afd7f78e;
  color:#2E9CFF;
  border: none;
  margin-left: .5em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is curious I found a solution, I used the computed properties to return 2 sets of days

```
<template>
 <div id="calendarContainer">
    
 <Calendar :attributes='attr' @dayclick='onDayClick' />
    
    <button class="arrowBtnsLeft" @click="monthBack">&#60;</button>
    <button class="arrowBtnsRight" @click="monthForward">&#62;</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Calendar from 'v-calendar/lib/components/calendar.umd'

export default {
  name: 'calendar', 
  components:{
      Calendar
},
  data() {
  
 
  return {
        days : [],
        counter: 0
    
  };
},
computed:{

dates() {
  return this.days.map(day => day.date);

    },
 
    attr() {
      const date = new Date();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.getMonth();
       
     return [this.dates.map(date => ({
        highlight:{class:'start'},
        dates: date,
      })),

      {
      highlight:'blue',
        dates: {
         start: new Date(year, month, 1), end:new Date(year, month, 1)
        }
      }
      ];
  
    },
},
methods: {
   onDayClick(day) {

      const idx = this.days.findIndex(d => d.id === day.id);
      if(this.counter > 1 || this.days.length > 2){
        this.days = []
        this.counter = 0
      }
      this.counter+=1
      if (idx >= 0) {
        this.days.splice(idx, 1);
      } else {
       

        this.days.push({
          id: day.id,
          date: day.date,
        })
        
       
        if(this.days.length == 2){
        this.attr[1].dates.start = this.days[0].date
        this.attr[1].dates.end = day.date
          
        }
      }
      console.log(this.days,'count',this.counter,'attributes',this.attr[1].dates,'days.length',this.days.length)
   }
      

    
    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know. it is a component that was written without regard to vueJS best practices or standards, I had to write a bunch of hacks like this to, just do ordinary things like hide the calendar.